# oauth_signature invalid error while using Magento Rest API with GET filters

Tags: magento-1.9, oauth

I'm having a hard time fetching orders from Magento REST API when I use its GET filters like `http://localhost/magento/api/rest/orders/?filter[1][attribute]=entity_id&filter[1][gt]=70&page=1&limit=100`

It is giving a `"error":[{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=signature_invalid"}]`

When I try hitting the same API endpoint using a REST Client like Postman, I'm getting back the desired results JSON.

I suspect the square brackets in the filter query might be causing a problem in generating a Oauth signature. All the endpoints without GET filters are working fine. I'm using the Request node module to make the GET request with the oauth headers.

Is there any fix to avoid the signature invalid error?

Comment: Is there any answer on this question or did you find a way to apply filter? i am also facing same problem

Comment: The problem was within the Request node module I was using to generate a OAuth signature.It didn't factor for square brackets in the URL. I modified the code in the module for including square brackets. Check the OAuth signature generation method you are using.

Comment: that is right after some time spend i got it resolved, thank you for your pointers.

Comment: I have the same problem. If the querystring contains square brackets the signature is invalid. How did you get to solve it?
Thanks you.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. How did you solved? The square brackets is encoding corretly and the querystring parameters order is ok but  I still getting invalid signature.

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this? It seems to only be when I have to encode filter values.

Comment: Have a look at this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176319/5888

Comment: I got same issue. I have been trying to get rid of this error. please help me if any one solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Did you managed to Encode the names and values of parameters?

I was having this issue too and [this](http://developer.pearson.com/creating-and-using-oauth-10a-signature) helped me.

You have to make sure that your signature base string parameters are in **alphabetic order** by parameter **name**

This is what i'm using to encode parameters in my signature base.

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
string webUnreservedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";
foreach (char symbol in url)
{
    if (webUnreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) != -1)
        result.Append(symbol);
    else
        result.Append('%' + ((int)symbol).ToString("X2"));
}
return result.ToString();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Welcome on Magento SE. Thanks for your answer. Although it is an answer to an old question, it may still be useful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with magento core functionality
vendor/magento/framework/Oauth/Oauth.php
Comment out line number 199.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is you have to convert the square brackets in the signature base string twice:

- [ => %5B =>  %255B
- ] => %5D =>  %255D